# Connecting to Database with Msqli API

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo

Help to adjust this script for me.
Connection to the database was written in MySQL I think, I tried using a diff connection with MySQLi but I seem to be missing something down the codes after the connection. Any help will be highly appreciated.
PHP codes are:

```
//my config
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $databasename = "subscribe";


   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "done!!";


$subscribe = (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] ==    
'unsubscribe')?false:true;

if ($subscribe){
$fields = array(
    array('name' => 'email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
    array('name' => 'name', 'valid' => array('require')),
);
}else{
$fields = array(
    array('name' => 'unsubscribe_email', 'valid' => array('require',  
'email')),
    array('name' => 'confirm', 'valid' => array('require'), 'err_message'
=> 'confirm'),
);
}
```

Above was the connection I did in mysqli.
now the lines below are the other part of the script which I am sure I am still missing something to make it work. It is an old subscription script I got from the net.

```
$error_fields = array();
$get = array();
foreach ($fields AS $field){
$value = isset($_POST[$field['name']])?$_POST[$field['name']]:'';
if (is_array($value)){
    $value = implode('/ ', $value);
}
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
$get[$field['name']] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
$is_valid = true;
$err_message = '';
if (!empty($field['valid'])){
    foreach ($field['valid'] AS $valid) {
        switch ($valid) {
            case 'require':
                $is_valid = $is_valid && strlen($value) > 0;
                $err_message = 'Field required';
                break;
            case 'email':
                $is_valid = $is_valid && preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-
   z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $value);
                $err_message = 'Email required';
                break;
            default:                
                break;
        }
    }
   }
   if (!$is_valid){
    if (!empty($field['err_message'])){
        $err_message = $field['err_message'];
    }
    $error_fields[] = array('name' => $field['name'], 'message' =>    
 $err_message);
 }
}

if (empty($error_fields)){
if ($subscribe){
    $data = array(
        'email' => "'".$get['email']."'",
        'name' => "'".$get['name']."'",
        'date_subscribe' => 'NOW()',
        'status' => "'T'",
    );
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO subscription_form (`".implode("`, `",    
 array_keys($data))."`) VALUES(".implode(", ", array_values($data)).")";
 }else{
    $sql = "UPDATE subscription_form SET date_unsubscribe = NOW(), status
 = 'F' WHERE email = '".$get['unsubscribe_email']."'";
}
if (!empty($sql)){
    $sql_result = mysqli_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request  
"Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
}
echo (json_encode(array('code' => 'success')));
}else{
echo json_encode(array('code' => 'failed', 'fields' => $error_fields));
}
```

Sorry to say I am kind of rushing ahead alto as I am sure I will get there gradually but I just need this done to finish some pho website I am developing.Any Help will be appreciated please. All I need is a bit of direction while I keep reading more to improve my skills in phhp and database. I am only about 1/4 into php and backend.

Comment: What's exactly your question and do you get any errors after runing your code?

Comment: first you are using $connection instead of $conn. second mysqli wants connection first and query after. So it is not $sql_result = mysqli_query ($sql, $connection ) but $sql_result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql)

Comment: BTW i can't see any PDO here in this question..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the line below, you have used the connection string as $connection, it should be $conn

```
$sql_result = mysqli_query ($sql, $connection )
```

So change above sentence to $sql_result = mysqli_query ($sql, $conn)
it should solve your problem

Comment: Could be worth checking the order of the parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the First part of the code i think you have to write the `if..else` block 
like below

```
if ($subscribe === true){
  echo 'In IF BLOCK<br />';
  $fields = array(
  array('name' => 'email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
   array('name' => 'name', 'valid' => array('require')),
 );

 }else if($subscribe === false){
   echo 'In the ELSE BLOCK <br />';
    $fields = array(
         array('name' => 'unsubscribe_email', 'valid' => array('require',  
         'email')),
         array('name' => 'confirm', 'valid' => array('require'), 
            'err_message' => 'confirm'),
           );

 } else{
    echo 'This else block i have written for clearification only';
}
```

============================================================

IN SHORT `if` and `else if` must contain the **condition** which is evaluated

```
if(condition1_for_evalute){

 } elseif(condition2_for_evalute){

 } else{

 }
```

Second block of code i didn't get what you want to ask. Sorry about that

Comment: the if condition OP posted has nothing wrong. It's perfectly valid

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys, I did a suggestions, the form cannot be submitted, maybe its a xampp problem. I will load it on al live server and run it see what comes out. and thanks for the suggestions.its a free form from php jabbers i try to update it.https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-subscription-form-script/

Comment: @FellaFr Did you get their form to work eventually with PHP7?